# Misleading Index During Series to DataFrame Pandas Transformation

Tags: python, pandas

I have created the aggregated function in pandas and save the result:

```
import pandas as pd
_dwh = df2_date[df2_date.STATUS == 'A']
       .groupby('Party_id')
       .DURATION_DWH.agg(np.mean)
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

Then, I tried to switch into a pandas `DataFrame` as follows:

```
df2_dwh = pd.DataFrame(_dwh)
```

It returned some confusing results:

[image]

How can I create a normal DataFrame with indices like `1,...,n` and `Party_id` and `Duration_DWH` like columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add parameter `as_index=False` or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
_dwh=df2_date[df2_date.STATUS=='A'].groupby('Party_id', as_index=False).DURATION_DWH.mean()

print (_dwh)
                 Party_id  DURATION_DWH
0  214BB440D604466275DFBB         574.0
1  214BB440D604466276D1B3         574.0
2  214BB440D604466371D1B2         558.5
3  214BB440D604466371DDB1         578.0
4  214BB440D604466373DBB5         578.0
```

---

```
_dwh=df2_date[df2_date.STATUS=='A'].groupby('Party_id', as_index=False).DURATION_DWH
                                   .mean()
                                   .reset_index()

print (_dwh)

                     Party_id  DURATION_DWH
    0  214BB440D604466275DFBB         574.0
    1  214BB440D604466276D1B3         574.0
    2  214BB440D604466371D1B2         558.5
    3  214BB440D604466371DDB1         578.0
    4  214BB440D604466373DBB5         578.0
```